# code behind confirm with custom validation

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, confirm

i understand that we able to achieve this by using "onClientClick", but i want to check the validation first BEFORE the confirmation box.

javascript

```
function showConfirm() {
         var result = window.confirm('Are you sure?');
         if (result == true)
             alert("ok");            
}
```

html

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

C#

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if(checkValidation() == true)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "scr",  "javascript:showConfirm();", true);

       //if(result == true)   //how to get the result value?
       //{
            ////run some code
            //insert data into sql
       //}
    }
 }
```

is there anyway i can get the confirmation result at code behind? without the if-else-statement, the data will insert into sql before user choose their decision.

Comment: You can use ajax to do your validation and the show the alert (on my opinion is not the best practice). You can do all validation with javascript and IF there is something that you need to get it from server (db field) then you can use ajax.

Comment: yes, i do need to get the data from sql before insert. what kind of ajax feature u meant? updatePanel?

Comment: Personally i avoid to use updatepanel. You can use ajax through jquery or pagemethods.

Comment: tq for the suggestion, but i can't believe i found a very simple solution for this. please see my answer :)

Comment: Postbacks are bad for no reason. Better use clentside code for validation.

Comment: my validation need to go through database, clientside script can do that securely?

Comment: If you do not with ajax whole page will be re-drown. Generally avoid these things on web because all the effort is on the server. securely? If someone wants to f!@#$@!# your business, will do it believe me :) . Generally ajax (on my opinion) is the best way to operate in web. But that's my opinion.

Comment: if you need your validation on sql side , so what i did for same scenario was, i declare a variable which is of output type inside my strored procedure and check there at sql side and return result  and show alert on the basis of output parameter...... or you can create your validation using javascript as well perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

1. i create a button with display:none

   .hideButton{
               display:none;
           }
2. create code behind

   protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               Response.Redirect("page2.aspx");
           }
3. trigger the btnConfirm click if user click Yes on  confirmation box

   $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnConfirm').trigger('click');

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a custom validation in Web forms that you much enable  `EnableClientScript="true"` and write the JS validate function name in  `ClientValidationFunction="JSValidateFunctionName"` like this you would be able to validate on client side before even going to server side.